# Can i set up a recurring credit card charge to an individual?

Tags: credit-card

I want to set up a recurring payment to a friend, and ideally, I would like to use a credit card to pay them.
Is there a way?
My friend would need a way to receive from or charge to my credit card - which is exactly what I want.
Any advice?
TIA

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. Your friend needs to open a merchant account with a processor of their choice.

Comment: Could you?  Sure.  Your friend could get a merchant account, sign up with a payment processor, and set up a system that just charged your card once a month.  Practically, however, that would be a very cumbersome and expensive way to set this up.  Your bank's bill pay will happily send your friend a check every month with very little setup work.  Your favorite P2P payment app may have a way to schedule transfers as well.

Comment: But the cashback.... Except that all the credit card rewards and cashbacks are paid by the merchants, it doesn't come out of nowhere.

Comment: Right. This is ignoring the fact that the person with the merchant account pays fees on every transaction. Whatever you are trying to do, this is probably the wrong way to do it, if it's possible at all. How about backing up a step and telling us why you want this? (I know folks who have merchant accounts, but that is because they are actually selling something and the fees are accounted for when they set prices.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with it, but apparently the Cash App [allows you to set up recurring payments](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/comprehensive-guide-cash-app-automaticrecurring-payments-tebid-kelly-bvhue#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20Cash%20App%3A%20Launch,payment%20and%20tap%20on%20it.), unlike most other peer-to-peer payment solutions.

Keep in mind that whatever solution you find, if you use a credit card there will be fees, paid either by you or by your recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CC this way is difficult and generally inadvisable unless your friend already has a way to receive CC payments (such as through a service, on which they will likely pay a fee).

The way credit cards work is as a revolving pool of money (or credit) that you can access with explicit rules for use and repayment. Credit cards are handled by a processor, who is almost never the bank you bank with. For example, Huntington Bank has their Debit/Credit Cards processed by MasterCard, and explicitly states that their CC cannot be used for recurring scheduled payments to a payee that you set up. You can always schedule a recurring payment with a merchant, but the merchant handles that interaction with the CC processor (through storing the card information or a token that authorizes them for a specific charge amount and timeframe).

To do what you're looking to do, account to account, would at best be considered a recurring cash advance on the credit card. At worst, you would have to manually manage the transfer each month and would risk having the account closed on you if the bank discovers what you are doing and considers it a violation of the account terms related to that card.

Peer-to-peer cash transfer services (which are handled by a processor as well) are probably how you want to do this. You link your CC to the service (or app) in question and use the service/app to make the transfer. Recommendations are not in-scope for this stack, but I'm sure your bank/CU either has one of their own, or one that they readily integrate with.

Comment: In the credit card world there are three entities: the issuer (Huntington Bank), the network (MasterCard), and the processor (whoever the merchant account is with). Usually the issuer and the processor are not the same (but could be), and the network is just an intermediary. In some cases, like with Amex or Discover, you may have the network also act as an issuer and/or processor.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get your ideal solution.

Many banks allow you to set up periodic payment to whomever you like, but it comes out of the checking account. I've gotten cash transfers this way, and sent a few. As long as there's sufficient balance in the sending account to cover the transfer it, it's pretty trivial.

If your bank doesn't support this, you might want to consider opening an account at a bank which does. Refilling it periodically is no harder than making a credit card payment.

And as others have noted, even if you could set up periodic credit card payments (eg via a third party service) you and your friend are going to have to cover the credit card company's vendor fees, which will probably exceed any advantages of using the card.

Answer (score -1):

Check with your bank, specifically an online portal if available, and examine the bill pay feature common with many institutions. I have in position exactly the circumstances you've noted (other than the option to charge to your card) an individual recurring payment. In my case, it's a credit union **checking account** as the source.

In order to implement this feature, the recipient must provide a destination account and routing numbers, usually checking, along with full name and phone number. This creates a bank-to-bank transfer on the schedule entered at the time of creation.

It's my error to have not emphasized that these transactions should be made between checking (possibly savings) accounts and not credit cards.

Comment: Note that not every bank/cu allows you to designate a CC account as the paying account , or will consider each of those payments to be a cash advance. You're effectively writing a check from the CC account to whoever is receiving the money, as opposed to the CC processor handling the transaction. As an example, Huntington Bank has their Debit/Credit Cards processed by MasterCard, and explicitly states that their CC cannot be used for recurring scheduled payments to a payee that you set up.

Comment: Second the last comment. Bill pay, at least in the US, sends cash to the recipient, so if credit cards are used to pay an arbitrary payee it would be treated as a cash advance and incur significant interest.